# Problema instalando ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, npm

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente comando

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado.

> npm WARN deprecated superagent@4.1.0: Please note that v5.0.1+ of
>   superagent removes User-Agent header by default, therefore you may
>   need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without a
>   User-Agent header).  This notice will go away with v5.0.2+ once it is
>   released. C:\Users\agutierrez0\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic ->
>   C:\Users\agutierrez0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
>   + ionic@5.2.7 added 224 packages from 168 contributors and updated 2 packages in 66.466s

Alguien podría ayudarme con este tema por favor.

Comment: Se instalao Ionic , solo te esta diciendo que npm que tiene una version obsoleta

Answer (score -1):

He tenido el mismo problema, la solución que tuve fue reinstalar nodejs en su última versión (12.10.0) y desde la consola de Windows ejecutar `npm i -g ionic`, aunque te sigue mostrando el problema del `superagent deprecated` funciona sin problemas.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Saludos.